# How to tell whether Little Snitch is running or stopped?

Tags: macos, security

I am running Little Snitch in demo mode:

[image]

After a few hours, how can I tell whether Little Snitch is running or stopped?

From the [official website](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/order.html):

> Free Evaluation License
>
> Little Snitch has a free, built-in demo mode that provides the same
>   protection and functionality as the full version. The demo runs for
>   three hours, and it can be restarted as often as you like. The Network
>   Monitor expires after 30 days.

How can I *restart* it when it's stopped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> After a few hours, how can I tell whether Little Snitch is running or stopped?

If you enable the »Show inactivity warning in menu bar« feature (right below the button in your screenshot) you will see a yellow triangle if Little Snitch is not running.

> How can I restart it when it's stopped?

If it is not running, the stop button will change to a start button. Press it to start Little Snitch for another 3 hours.